# python error - NameError:name download_url is not defined

Tags: python, json, curl

I am trying to parse out the json response from a cURL command using a vendor's restful API. The full command is:

```
curl -s "url" -H "api" | python - c "import sys, json; print;(json.load(sys.stdin)["download_url"]);"
```

I keep getting an error that says NameError:name 'download_url' is not defined. Thoughts on how to fix this?

Comment: I've edited the question to show the code as code and SO's syntax highlighter shows the problem right there: `download_url` is not part of the quoted string. BTW, the `;` after `print` is also wrong - it would print nothing.

Answer (score 2):

Change `"` for `'` in `download_url`. Using `"download_url"` you are closing first the `"`. Due that `download_url` is not longer belongs to python string command

```
curl -s "url" -H "api" | python - c "import sys, json; print;(json.load(sys.stdin)['download_url']);"
```